# Why do we use $Df$ rather than $f'$ for the derivative of a multivariable function?

Tags: derivatives, notation, math-history

Is there any reason we use $Df$ for derivatives of multivariable functions but $f'$ derivatives of single variable functions despite having a definition that works for both:

$$Df(c) = f'(c) = L \iff \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x) - f(c) - L(x-c)}{||x-c||} = 0$$

Comment: You could do this. I've seen people do $f'_x$ to refer to the $x$ partial though.

Comment: I'm asking why the notation changed when multivariable calculus was created, rather than keeping the old $f'$ notation.

Comment: The notation didn't necessarily change. $f'$ is [Lagrange's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Lagrange's_notation) and $Df$ is [Euler's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Euler's_notation). Both of them had notations for multivariate functions, $f^{'}_{''}$ vs $D_{xy}$ for example. I'm not entirely sure if you can pin down a reason why Euler's is more popular for multiple variables, but I can guess that it's just do to clarity. And Lagrange's notation is clearer and more concise for a single variable.

Comment: I think the main reason is that there's much more complexity in multivariate derivatives. You have total derivatives, partial derivatives, and the Jacobian. Spivak uses prime notation to refer to the Jacobian in "Calculus on Manifolds", so it's not entirely abandoned.